# Slow updates with Entity Framework 4.3 and SQL Server Compact Edition 3.5

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sql-server-ce

I am developing a WPF application that uses a SQL Server Compact Edition database and Entity Framework, but I get really slow performance of updates and deletes. So I created a simple `Foobar` console application (below) and got the same issue.

I understand that Entity Framework creates some overhead and that SQL Server Compact Edition is slower than an regular SQL Server. But is it this much difference between a `INSERT` and an `UPDATE/DELETE`?

**Main**

```
    public static void CreateFoobars()
    {
        DateTime start = DateTime.Now;

        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
        {
            Foobar foobar = new Foobar();
            foobar.FoobarID = i;
            foobar.Column1 = "Column1";
            foobar.Column2 = "Column2";
            foobar.Column3 = "Column3";
            foobar.Column4 = "Column4";

            _localRepository.CreateFoobar(foobar);
        }

        bool result = _localRepository.Save();

        TimeSpan timeSpan = CalculateTimeSpan(start, DateTime.Now);

        Console.WriteLine("Created Foobars? {0}, Time: {1}", result, timeSpan);
    }

    public static void CountFoobars()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Count Foobars: {0}", _localRepository.GetAllFoobars().Count());
    }

    public static void UpdateFoobars()
    {
        DateTime start = DateTime.Now;

        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
        {
            Foobar foobar = new Foobar();
            foobar.FoobarID = i;
            foobar.Column1 = "Column11";
            foobar.Column2 = "Column22";
            foobar.Column3 = "Column33";
            foobar.Column4 = "Column44";

            _localRepository.UpdateFoobar(foobar);
        }

        bool result = _localRepository.Save();

        TimeSpan timeSpan = CalculateTimeSpan(start, DateTime.Now);

        Console.WriteLine("Updated Foobars? {0}, Time: {1}", result, timeSpan);
    }

    public static void DeleteFoobars()
    {
        DateTime start = DateTime.Now;

        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
        {
            _localRepository.DeleteFoobar(i);
        }

        bool result = _localRepository.Save();

        TimeSpan timeSpan = CalculateTimeSpan(start, DateTime.Now);

        Console.WriteLine("Deleted Foobars? {0}, Time: {1}", result, timeSpan);
    }
```

**Repository**

```
    public IQueryable<Foobar> GetAllFoobars()
    {
        return _entities.Foobars;
    }

    public Foobar GetFoobar(int foobarID)
    {
        return _entities.Foobars.ByFoobarID(foobarID).FirstOrDefault();
    }

    public bool CreateFoobar(Foobar foobar)
    {
        try
        {
            _entities.AddToFoobars(foobar);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
        }

        return false;
    }

    public bool UpdateFoobar(Foobar foobar)
    {
        try
        {
            Foobar f = this.GetFoobar(foobar.FoobarID);

            if (f != null)
            {

                f.Column1 = foobar.Column1;
                f.Column2 = foobar.Column2;
                f.Column3 = foobar.Column3;
                f.Column4 = foobar.Column4;

                return true;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
        }

        return false;
    }

    public bool DeleteFoobar(int foobarID)
    {
        try
        {
            Foobar f = this.GetFoobar(foobarID);

            if (f != null)
            {
                _entities.DeleteObject(f);

                return true;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
        }

        return false;
    }

    public bool Save()
    {
        try
        {
            this.Context.SaveChanges();

            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
        }

        return false;
    }
```

**Results** (on a i7 with SSD and 16 RAM, almost doubled time on a older C2D)

- Count Foobars: 0
- Created Foobars? True, Time: 00:00:04:0700057
- Count Foobars: 10000
- Update Foobars? True, Time: 00:00:59:8800838
- Count Foobars: 10000
- Deleted Foobars? True, Time: 00:00:57:8000810
- Count Foobars: 0

**Tested**

- LazyLoading = false
- Disabling identities in database.

Comment: Never found any solution for this problem, I switched to SQL Express instead.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that your create function faster because it is just creating 10000 local objects  and then committing them all in one step to the database, while your delete and update functions all query one item from the database before changing it.

Comment: Yes, but there is no other way of updating or deleting? And selecting one Foobar is fast, so why the performance hit when updating or deleting? Is SQL Compact Edition always this slow with Entity Framework? If so, then I have to build my WPF application around SQL Express instead or try updating and deleting without Entity Framework.